# Excel formula doesn't work on formula results

Tags: excel, countif

I have a range of numbers (Y6:AC6) which are obtained as a function of =RIGHT(Text,Num) formula. When I try to apply COUNTIFS formula on these numbers which you can see on the picture, it doesn't work. However, when I try the same formula on actual numbers, but not functional results of RIGHT(Text,Num), it works. What am I missing here? can someone help me please? thanks.

[image]

Comment: precede your Right formula with `--` so: `=--RIGHT(Text,Num)`  It will make the text numbers

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, this solves the problem. Thanks a lot ! but I can't accept your answer in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for this - I finally understand what `--` means and what it's for. Not sure it's clearer than `Value()` though.

Comment: @JackDeeth not clearer, but less typing.